# Reasoning about lists in Coq

Tags: coq

I'm try to solve some theorems, based on Pierce's "Software Foundations".

First of all I create a couple of useful functions:

```
Inductive natlist: Type :=
  | nil: natlist
  | cons : nat -> natlist -> natlist.

Notation "x :: l" := (cons x l) (at level 60, right associativity).

Fixpoint repeat (n count: nat): natlist :=
    match count with
      | O => nil
      | S count' => n :: (repeat n count')
    end.

  Fixpoint length (l: natlist): nat :=
    match l with
      | nil => O
      | h :: t => S (length t)
    end.

 Theorem count_repeat: forall n: nat, length (repeat n n) = n.
  Proof.
    intros n. induction n as [| n'].
    simpl. reflexivity.
    simpl. (* and here I can't continue... *)
```

I want to follow Pierce's advice:

> Note that, since this problem is somewhat open-ended, it's possible
>   that you may come up with a theorem which is true, but whose proof
>   requires techniques you haven't learned yet. Feel free to ask for help
>   if you get stuck!

So, could you please advice some proof techniques for me?

Comment: The two arguments of `repeat` do not have the same meaning at all. In particular, in your theorem, the values of the list are not important. You should try to prove a more general lemma using distinct variables for the values and the length.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @eponier said, you should try to prove a more general lemma, like

```
Theorem count_repeat_gen: forall m n: nat, length (repeat n m) = m.
```

Using `repeat n n` creates an implicit link between the value of the element and the size of the list which makes your statement impossible to prove directly. Once you proved `count_repeat_gen`, you'll be able to prove your theorem.

Comment: Thanks for help! I prove it by induction.